# Why do I get a NullPointerException while trying to begin transaction?

Tags: java, jpa, nullpointerexception, cdi, named-entity-recognition

Before I was getting NullPointerException in this line

```
EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

but I fixed it by adding one line above

```
emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("main");
```

Now I am getting NullPointerException in this line

```
transaction.begin();
```

I can't understand why. I was trying to take it from the try catch block but was getting the same result. Also in the finally I tried to add emf.close(); but the error doesn't get fixed. Also, I include @Named annotation because someone suggested me to do that.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named; 
import javax.inject.Inject; 
import java.sql.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery ; 
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;
import javax.transaction.RollbackException; 
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

@Named
public class UserManager implements Serializable{

   @PersistenceUnit(unitName="main")
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   @Resource
   private UserTransaction transaction;

   public UserManager() {}

   public UserTransaction getTransaction() { return transaction; }
   public void setTransaction(UserTransaction transaction) { this.transaction = transaction; }

   public void addUser(User v) throws Exception {
    emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("main");
        EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
        boolean commit;
        try {   
    transaction.begin();
        manager.joinTransaction();
    commit = false;
        try {
        manager.persist(v);
        transaction.commit();
        commit = true;
        }finally {
                if(commit==false){
            transaction.rollback();
                }
         }
        }finally {     
         manager.close();
             //emf.close();
    }
   }



@Named("subBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{

   private List<User> users;
   private UserManager vm;
   private User v;
   private int total;

   public UserBean() {
      this.total= 0;
      users = new ArrayList<User>();
      vm = new UserManager();
      v = new User();
   }

   public String addUserAction() throws Exception {
      vm.addUser(v);
      users = getUsers();
      return "submit1";

   }

   //getters and setters 
}
```

Comment: You declare transaction but it's not being initialized. Are you calling setTransaction() before you call addUser()?

Comment: @shaunc it should be injected by CDI.

Comment: Looks like you're initializing `UserManager` class manually, so CDI cannot inject the respective variables. If you're doing the work manually, then you should not use CDI or should review if you're following the proper design.

Comment: I call addUser()from the other class that is a CDI bean and has at Named at RequestScoped and in that class I have an AddUserAction method that calls addUser in theUserManager class. I do have get and setTransaction methods above the addUser method but I am not calling them anywhere. THey are there bc I use  @Resource private UserTransaction transaction;

Comment: @user1282256 provide the necessary code to see how you do this.

Comment: I have uppdated my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the problem is that you're creating an instance of `UserManager` bean manually and CDI cannot inject the variables. This is noted here:

```
@Named("subBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
   //variable is just declared...
   private UserManager vm;

   public UserBean() {
      //and here you're initializing it manually...
      vm = new UserManager();
   }

   //rest of your code...
}
```

Let CDI do its work by injecting the variable:

```
@Named("subBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
   //variable is just declared
   //and notify CDI it should inject an instance when creating an instance of the client class
   @Inject
   private UserManager vm;

   public UserBean() {
      //no need to initialize it ever
      //vm = new UserManager();
   }

   //rest of your code...
}
```

By doing this, you won't need to create any field that should be injected in your other bean either, which means you don't need to initialize `emf` field manually:

```
//this line should be commented as well...
//emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("main");
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem. It is also good that I didn't close EntityManagerFactory because I was able to get my users and also store them in the database.